# strange for loop in code

Tags: java

I started to study on observer design pattern and I have got some problems by analyzing code.

```
public void notifyObservers() {
    for (Observer ob : observers) {
        System.out.println("Notifying Observers on change in Loan interest rate");
        ob.update(this.interest);
    }
}
```

and I didn't understand this part: `Observer ob : observers` what this stands for?

Comment: That's a "for-each" loop. It would be similar to `for (int i = 0; i < observers.length; i++){observers[i].update(this.interest);}`;

Comment: As people show, it is [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the Observer pattern.  It's basic Java syntax.

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator<Observer> itr = observers.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
{
   Observer ob = itr.next();
   ...
}
```

But.. more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For every object which implement `Observer` interface in collection `observers` do this:

```
System.out.println("Notifying Observers on change in Loan interest rate");
ob.update(this.interest);
```

`ob` is tempory name in `for-each` loop for every object from collection `observers`